# Visual studio crashes when using intellisense with the mouse in Activity Library

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Fully updated VS2015 Enterprise in question.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new Activity Library project (Templates/Visual C#/Workflow/Activity Libray)
2. Add single writeline control
3. Input "any text" (quotation marks included), press . (dot)
4. When intellisense appears select anything with a double mouse click
5. VS crashes

Any ideas how to bypass the problem or at least has anyone had the same problem?
Or if you're willing to test it on other versions of VS it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from Microsoft. No plans to fix it in 2015. Fixed in 2017.